# How do i redirect client on form submit using HTML

Tags: html, forms, post

I know how to accomplish this in `PHP`. Is is possible to redirect using only `HTML`, After form get submitted?

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST" />
```

Comment: Redirect is done with `header("Location: /path/here")` function.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: But not in PHP, in HTML? Why tag the question with PHP, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On submit(you have a submit button named submit) and hopefully named form input's such as `<input type='text' name='usernameFromForm' />`

fire the header function

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $_POST['usernameFromForm'];
    // Do something with this variable, put into database, etc
    // Redirect
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
}
```

Comment: i want to do it in html,one post it and go in another page,i mean the php should post background and html to be redirected to another page separately

Comment: that's what this does...

Answer (score 0):

After you preform some tasks with the $_POST data in your login.php page, use the [PHP header()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp) function to determine the location to go to. Use header() before any HTML is printed.